# ERROR: No unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, database-schema, ddl

For some reason I'm getting an error* in my code. I'm quite new to PostgreSQL, and simply SQL. What is causing this error?

*there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "tech".

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE Person (
    person_id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname   VARCHAR(128),
    lastname    VARCHAR(128),
    email_adr   VARCHAR(128),

    UNIQUE(person_id, email_adr)
);

CREATE TABLE Phone (
    person_id   INT REFERENCES Person(person_id),
    phone_nr    INT PRIMARY KEY,

    UNIQUE(phone_nr)
);


CREATE TABLE Tech (
    tech_id INT REFERENCES Person(person_id),
    username    VARCHAR(80) PRIMARY KEY,
    password    VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    location    Varchar(128),

    UNIQUE(username, tech_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer (
    customer_id    INT REFERENCES Persons(person_id),
    addresse       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

    UNIQUE(customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Task (
    task_id     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    payment     MONEY,
    tech        INT REFERENCES Tech(tech_id)         NOT NULL,
    customer    INT REFERENCES Customer(customer_id) NOT NULL,
    start_date  DATE                                 NOT NULL,
    end_dato    DATE,

    UNIQUE(tech, customer, start_date, end_date)
);

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In table `Task` you trying to reference to table `Tech` by `tech_id`. To do that you must add `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` to `tech_id` in `Tech`.
Right now in table `Tech` you have `UNIQUE(username, tech_id)` that means that values in column `tech_id` could by doubled Ex.

```
Tech
-------------------------------
tech_id     username,    ....
------------------------------
1           'John'
2           'Tony'
1           'Nataly'
```

Acctually the better idea is to set reference by `PRIMARY KEY`, so in your case `username` in table `Tech`.

If you want to leave structure the way present in question, you should just add `UNIQUE(tech_id)` in column `Tech`.

Comment: Isn't that what I've done? "UNIQUE(username, tech_id)" 

Edit: Ah, I see. Let me check

Comment: @ServO No, as I write in example **`UNIQUE(username, tech_id)` means that pair of columns should by unique**. (1, 'John'), (1, 'Nataly') are unique in that terms. Column `tech_id` alone isn't.

Comment: That explains a lot. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this code?

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE Person (
    person_id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname   VARCHAR(128),
    lastname    VARCHAR(128),
    email_adr   VARCHAR(128),

    UNIQUE(person_id),
    UNIQUE(email_adr)
);

CREATE TABLE Phone (
    person_id   INT,
    phone_nr    INT PRIMARY KEY,
);


CREATE TABLE Tech (
    tech_id INT,
    username    VARCHAR(80) PRIMARY KEY,
    password    VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    location    Varchar(128),

    FOREIGN KEY(tech_id) REFERENCES Person(person_id),
    UNIQUE(username),
    UNIQUE(tech_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer (
    customer_id    INT REFERENCES Persons(person_id),
    addresse       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY(tech_id) REFERENCES Person(person_id),
    UNIQUE(customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Task (
    task_id     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    payment     MONEY,
    tech        varchar(80) REFERENCES Tech(username)       NOT NULL,
    customer    INT        REFERENCES Customer(customer_id) NOT NULL,
    start_date  DATE                                 NOT NULL,
    end_dato    DATE,

    UNIQUE(tech, customer, start_date, end_date)
);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: This should works. But as I see you can modify tables structure, Is relation between `Tech` and `Person` one-to-one (that means that each username can be owned by one and only one person)? If so, I would  rather consider changing `PRIMARY KEY` in `Tech` to `tech_id` and changing `tech` column in `Task` to `tech_id   INT REFERENCES Tech(tech_id)       NOT NULL,`. `PRIMARY KEY` and `FOREIGN KEY` checks on `INT` may be cheaper than on text types.

Comment: @Gabriel'sMessanger Ahh, I will try to do so. But I have 1 final question. I've already made a model of my SQL in ORM(2) and in that model I specify that in Task, end_date has to be greater than start_date - How do I do that with code?

Comment: you mean SQL code? [`CHECK CONSTRAINT` is what you looking for](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html). In this case you add in table definition `CHECK (end_date > start_date)` just as you did with `UNIQUE(...)`.

Comment: @Gabriel'sMessanger Damn, you're such an angel :)) Thanks!